# Get ids of many to many table

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many

in django if there's table with many to many field like that :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    sport = models.ManyToManyField(Sport)
```

when you try to get all objects from this table you do this :

```
Category.objects.all()
```

and the result will be like that after serializing :

```
    "data": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "name": '..'
       "icon": '...'
       "sport": [
          1,
          2
      ]
    ]
   }
```

so my question here how to achieve the same result using pure sql
I tried this :

```
sql = '''select a.*,b.sport_id,array_agg(b.sport_id) as sport from category a join category_sport b on b.category_id=a.id group by a.id,b.sport_id ;'''
```

but the result was like that :

```
"data": [
  {
   "id": 1,
    "name": '..'
    "icon": '...'
    "sport": [
      1,
      ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": '..'
    "icon": '...'
    "sport": [
          2
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: i did not understand your question will you be please more specific

Comment: i guess you want to render data from db in you template

Comment: it's not about django template at all it's about sql so what i want is just get the result of objects.all() in django in sql with manytomany field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, if you need to achieve that you just need to remove `b.sport_id`, you want to concatenate the `sport_id` into an array for each category, so no reason to group by this field, your SQL should be:

```py
sql = '''select a.id, array_agg(b.sport_id) as sport from category a join category_sport b on b.category_id=a.id group by a.id;'''
```

Remember, all nonaggregate selected fields should appear in the group by section.

Another alternative, if you are using PostgreSQL, can be to use the `ArrayAgg`, something like:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Category.objects.aggregate(sport=ArrayAgg('sport__id'))
```

Also, you can see this very simple PostgreSQL 13 example:

Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
  id INT,
  title VARCHAR(128)
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id INT
);

CREATE TABLE ab (
  id INT,
  aid INT,
  bid INT
);

INSERT INTO a (id, title) VALUES (1, 'title_a');
INSERT INTO a (id, title) VALUES (2, 'title_b');

INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (6);

INSERT INTO ab (id, aid, bid) VALUES(1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO ab (id, aid, bid) VALUES(2, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO ab (id, aid, bid) VALUES(3, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO ab (id, aid, bid) VALUES(4, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO ab (id, aid, bid) VALUES(5, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO ab (id, aid, bid) VALUES(6, 2, 6);
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.title, array_agg(ab.bid) AS bs FROM a JOIN ab ON a.id=ab.aid GROUP BY a.id, a.title;
```

Result:

```
| id  | title   | bs      |
| --- | ------- | ------- |
| 2   | title_b | [2,4,6] |
| 1   | title_a | [1,3,5] |
```

You can test it on https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: You cannot do that u will got an error with "b.sport_id" must appear in the GROUP BY.
I think it's not possible to achieve that in just one sql query

Comment: You are right! but that is just because you are including `b.sport_id` also in your select, so just remove it from the select and the group_by, I have updated my answer because I didn't realize you are including that field in the first place, I have updated my answer.

Comment: but there's an issue if we didn't insert items to table ab which happens when we create a new record in table a with null value in manytomany field so in this case when we execute the query we won't get the records with null value in manytomany field

Comment: and also I found that the query takes much time than it should to execute so do you think there's another way to get better performance like using ARRAY instead of array_agg

Comment: Not sure if I understood well, but there is no reason to set a null value to the ManyToManyField, remember this is not a real field on the database, it is a **Manager** similar to `.objects` for the models, you can use it to do operations like queries or updates in the intermediate table, you can see very good examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: And about the performance, the example schema that I posted in my answer is also a good example of things that shouldn't be done when you want good performance in queries, I've omitted intentionally the primary and foreign indexes in the tables to give a clear example. The performance of your queries will improve dramatically if you include those indexes.

Comment: I know that I already have the primary and foreign indexes but still the performance is not good comparing to django so  this query takes about 0.2 to 1 sec to execute while django takes about 0.0 sec to execute it's a huge different

Comment: It is difficult to say what is happening, if you are using the ArrayAgg aggregation in your query, it should translate into a single SQL statement, but things like prefetch_related translates into two queries. You can see the SQL statement executing and trying to understand why Django's query is better. In general, the JOIN statement is expensive, maybe two queries are the best option here.